# Get current opened browser window in selenium 2 (WebDriver)

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am using selenium 2 (WebDriver) now and I would like to get the control of current opened browser window instead of open a new one. That means I can't use driver.get("url") which is showed in all online documents. Could anyone help?

FYI, I am using Python binding of selenium and firefox. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't connect to an open browser at the moment. There is an open [bug](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=18) for WebDriver to support that

Comment: thanks a lot! Is there any other testing framework that has this feature?

Comment: Is Selenium now able to access the currently open browser window?